# Install another Command Line Tool version in XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

In Preferences -> Locations there is an option called Command Line Tools in which there is a list of different versions.

I did have 2 xcode versions installed 6.2 and 6.3, when I had both installed I could switch to 6.2 to use Swift 1.1 and to 6.3 to use Swift 1.2.

But today I updated to XCode 6.3.2 and it removed my XCode 6.2 so now I cant choose another Command Line Tools version.

Now I could just download the whole XCode 6.2 again but that is quite big and Im thin on storage. I found [Apple development center downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) where I could download and install different version I installed 'Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) for Xcode 6.2' but I still cannot see 6.2 as option inside Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools.

Obviously Im doing something wrong, anyone that can help me?

Comment: How about from the command line?  In other words can you use `xcode-select` to switch between the two different toolchains?

Comment: @trojanfoe How do I do that? I mean to switch version from 6.3.2 to 6.2?

Comment: Well, AFAIK, that UI in Xcode is just an interface to `xcode-select` and the tools you select only affect what's run from the command line.  I assume you actually use the command line to run these tools?

Comment: @trojanfoe So is there A difference? How can I see installed versions in terminal?

Comment: You can't, as such, but you use `xcode-select` to switch between the different toolchains contained in the different versions of Xcode.app you have installed on your system.  So it depends where they are installed and what they are called.  What I would really like to know, however, is are you actually using the tools from the command line, as I think you might be thinking you are selecting which compilers are used while within Xcode.  I cannot tell if you understand this or not.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes I think Im selecting compiler, maybe Im very wrong about it but thats the similarity I found about the versions from when I had 2 xcode versions installed. So I have to install whole xcode 6.2 to use Swift 1.1 again?

Comment: Yes.  And you need to actually run Xcode 6.2 in order to use Swift 1.1 from within Xcode.  Download the different versions from the Apple Developer Download site and install them as `Xcode62.app`, etc.